# unable to create a vector in R

Tags: r

I want to create a vector in R with a long list of strings, but for some reason the code runs without producing an error or generating the vector. As far as I can tell there are no syntactic errors in the code.

```
 myvars <- c("sale_year", "sale_mnth", "end_duration_mean", "ln_end_duration_mean", "one_by_end_duration_mean", "end_duration_class_2_dummy_mean", "end_duration_class_3_dummy_mean", "end_duration_class_4_dummy_mean", "end_duration_class_5_dummy_mean", "end_duration_class_6_dummy_mean", "end_duration_class_23_dummy_mean", "end_duration_class_56_dummy_mean", "on_dummy_mean", "of_dummy_mean", "n_dummy_mean", "nof_dummy_mean", "non_dummy_mean", "ofon_dummy_mean", "nn_dummy_mean", "nf_dummy_mean", "lifecycle_sale_mean", "mnth_vs_new_model_mean", "sin_mnth_vs_new_model_mean", "ln_mnth_vs_new_model_mean", "sqrt_mnth_vs_new_model_mean", "mnth_vs_new_model_n_mean", "mnth_vs_new_model_of_mean", "mnth_vs_new_model_on_mean", "mnth_vs_new_model_nof_mean", "mnth_vs_new_model_non_mean", "mnth_vs_new_model_ofon_mean", "sqrt_mnth_vs_new_model_n_mean", "sqrt_mnth_vs_new_model_of_mean", "sqrt_mnth_vs_new_model_on_mean", "sqrt_mnth_vs_new_model_nof_mean", "sqrt_mnth_vs_new_model_non_mean", "sqrt_mnth_vs_new_model_ofon_mean", "ln_mnth_vs_new_model_n_mean", "ln_mnth_vs_new_model_of_mean", "ln_mnth_vs_new_model_on_mean", "ln_mnth_vs_new_model_nof_mean", "ln_mnth_vs_new_model_non_mean", "ln_mnth_vs_new_model_ofon_mean", "sin_mnth_vs_new_model_n_mean", "sin_mnth_vs_new_model_of_mean", "sin_mnth_vs_new_model_on_mean", "sin_mnth_vs_new_model_nof_mean", "sin_mnth_vs_new_model_non_mean", "sin_mnth_vs_new_model_ofon_mean", "ln_lifecycle_sale_mean", "sqrt_lifecycle_sale_mean", "lifecycle_sale_n_mean", "lifecycle_sale_of_mean", "lifecycle_sale_on_mean", "lifecycle_sale_nof_mean", "lifecycle_sale_non_mean", "lifecycle_sale_ofon_mean", "sqrt_lifecycle_sale_n_mean", "sqrt_lifecycle_sale_of_mean", "sqrt_lifecycle_sale_on_mean", "sqrt_lifecycle_sale_nof_mean", "sqrt_lifecycle_sale_non_mean", "sqrt_lifecycle_sale_ofon_mean", "ln_lifecycle_sale_n_mean", "ln_lifecycle_sale_of_mean", "ln_lifecycle_sale_on_mean", "ln_lifecycle_sale_nof_mean", "ln_lifecycle_sale_non_mean", "ln_lifecycle_sale_ofon_mean", "lifecycle_age_mean", "ln_lifecycle_age_mean", "sin_lifecycle_age_mean", "sqrt_lifecycle_age_mean", "lifecycle_age_class_mean", "lifecycle_age_n_mean", "ln_lifecycle_age_n_mean", "sin_lifecycle_age_n_mean", "sqrt_lifecycle_age_n_mean", "lifecycle_age_of_mean", "ln_lifecycle_age_of_mean", "sin_lifecycle_age_of_mean", "sqrt_lifecycle_age_of_mean", "lifecycle_age_on_mean", "ln_lifecycle_age_on_mean", "sin_lifecycle_age_on_mean", "sqrt_lifecycle_age_on_mean", "lifecycle_age_nof_mean", "ln_lifecycle_age_nof_mean", "sin_lifecycle_age_nof_mean", "sqrt_lifecycle_age_nof_mean", "lifecycle_age_non_mean", "ln_lifecycle_age_non_mean", "sin_lifecycle_age_non_mean", "sqrt_lifecycle_age_non_mean", "lifecycle_age_ofon_mean", "ln_lifecycle_age_ofon_mean", "sin_lifecycle_age_ofon_mean", "sqrt_lifecycle_age_ofon_mean", "segment_small_dummy_mean", "segment_medium_dummy_mean", "segment_high_dummy_mean", "segment_monovolumes_dummy_mean", "segment_cabrio_dummy_mean", "segment_suv_dummy_mean", "other_segment_dummy_mean", "cat_prijs_mean", "ln_cat_prijs_mean", "one_by_cat_prijs_mean", "rw_per_mean", "optie_per_mean", "optie_per_2_mean", "optie_per_3_mean", "ln_optie_per_mean", "one_by_optie_per_mean", "accs_per_mean", "accs_per_2_mean", "accs_per_3_mean", "ln_accs_per_mean", "one_by_accs_per_mean", "optie_accs_per_mean", "optie_accs_per_2_mean", "optie_accs_per_3_mean", "ln_optie_accs_per_mean", "one_by_optie_accs_per_mean", "schade_per_mean", "schade_dummy_mean", "schade_per_2_mean", "schade_per_3_mean", "ln_schade_per_mean", "one_by_schade_per_mean", "kort_per_mean", "kort_per_2_mean", "kort_per_3_mean", "ln_kort_per_mean", "one_by_kort_per_mean", "end_kms_mean", "end_kms_2_mean", "end_kms_3_mean", "ln_end_kms_mean", "one_by_end_kms_mean", "end_kms_class_mean", "kms_per_year_mean", "lux_dummy_mean", "doors2_dummy_mean", "doors3_dummy_mean", "ln_motor_kw_mean", "sqrt_motor_kw_mean", "one_by_motor_kw_mean", "motor_pk_per_cc_mean", "euro3_dummy_mean", "euro4_dummy_mean", "euro5_dummy_mean", "euro6_dummy_mean", "tijd_mean", "wit_dummy_mean", "break_dummy_mean", "cabrio_dummy_mean", "mono_dummy_mean", "viermaalvier_dummy_mean", "berline_dummy_mean", "sport_dummy_mean", "coupe_dummy_mean", "roadster_dummy_mean", "missing_bodytype_dummy_mean", "uitvoering_base_dummy_mean", "uitvoering_comfort_dummy_mean", "uitvoering_high_dummy_mean", "uitvoering_sport_dummy_mean", "uitvoering_vip_dummy_mean", "tractie_v_dummy_mean", "tractie_a_dummy_mean", "tractie_4x4_dummy_mean", "tractie_unk_dummy_mean", "business_dummy_mean", "sale_b2b_dummy_mean", "sale_b2c_dummy_mean", "ck_kms_10000_mean", "ck_kms_30000_mean", "ck_kms_50000_mean", "ck_kms_70000_mean", "ck_kms_90000_mean", "ck_kms_110000_mean", "ck_kms_130000_mean", "ck_kms_150000_mean", "ck_kms_170000_mean", "ck_kms_190000_mean", "ck_kms_210000_mean", "ck_dur_1_mean", "ck_dur_2_mean", "ck_dur_3_mean", "ck_dur_4_mean", "ck_dur_5_mean", "ck_dur_6_mean", "ck_kpy_5000_mean", "ck_kpy_15000_mean", "ck_kpy_22500_mean", "ck_kpy_27500_mean", "ck_kpy_32500_mean", "ck_kpy_37500_mean", "ck_kpy_42500_mean", "ck_kpy_47500_mean", "ck_kpy_55000_mean", "ck_kpy_65000_mean", "kms_k60000_dummy_mean", "kms_k70000_dummy_mean", "kms_k80000_dummy_mean", "kms_k90000_dummy_mean", "kms_k100000_dummy_mean", "kms_k110000_dummy_mean", "kms_k120000_dummy_mean", "kms_g130000_dummy_mean", "kms_g140000_dummy_mean", "kms_g150000_dummy_mean", "kms_g160000_dummy_mean", "kms_per_year_k10000_dummy_mean", "kms_per_year_k20000_dummy_mean", "kms_per_year_k30000_dummy_mean", "kms_per_year_g40000_dummy_mean", "kms_per_year_g50000_dummy_mean", "kms_per_year_g60000_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_l100_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_100_110_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_110_120_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_120_130_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_130_140_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_140_150_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_150_160_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_160_170_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_170_180_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_180_190_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_190_200_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_m200_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_l110_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_l120_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_l130_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_l140_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_l150_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_l160_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_l170_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_l180_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_l190_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_l200_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_l1000_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_1000_1250_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_1250_1500_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_1500_1750_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_1750_2000_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_2000_2250_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_2250_2500_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_2500_2750_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_2750_3000_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_m3000_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_l1250_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_l1500_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_l1750_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_l2000_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_l2250_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_l2500_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_l2750_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_l3000_dummy_mean", "kort_m5_dummy_mean", "kort_m10_dummy_mean", "kort_m15_dummy_mean", "kort_m20_dummy_mean", "kort_0to5_dummy_mean", "kort_5to10_dummy_mean", "kort_10to15_dummy_mean", "kort_15to20_dummy_mean", "optie_m5_dummy_mean", "optie_m10_dummy_mean", "optie_m15_dummy_mean", "optie_m20_dummy_mean", "optie_0to5_dummy_mean", "optie_5to10_dummy_mean", "optie_10to15_dummy_mean", "optie_15to20_dummy_mean", "optie_accs_m5_dummy_mean", "optie_accs_m10_dummy_mean", "optie_accs_m15_dummy_mean", "optie_accs_m20_dummy_mean", "optie_accs_0to5_dummy_mean", "optie_accs_5to10_dummy_mean", "optie_accs_10to15_dummy_mean", "optie_accs_15to20_dummy_mean", "schade_0to5_dummy_mean", "schade_5to10_dummy_mean", "schade_10to15_dummy_mean", "schade_15to20_dummy_mean", "schade_m5_dummy_mean", "schade_m10_dummy_mean", "schade_m15_dummy_mean", "schade_m20_dummy_mean", "kort_per_class_mean", "optie_per_class_mean", "schade_per_class_mean", "motor_pk_class_mean", "motor_inhoud_class_mean", "zwart_dummy_mean", "rood_dummy_mean", "bruin_dummy_mean", "geel_dummy_mean", "groen_dummy_mean", "blauw_dummy_mean", "grijs_dummy_mean", "geen_kleur_dummy_mean", "dubbel_kleur_dummy_mean", "automaat_2000min_dummy_mean", "automaat_2000plus_dummy_mean", "dal_dummy_mean", "premiumlease_dummy_mean", "saablease_dummy_mean", "leasesense_dummy_mean", "privatesale_dummy_mean", "cars_sold_1mnth_mean", "cars_sold_3mnth_mean", "cars_sold_6mnth_mean", "cars_sold_1mnth_seg_mean", "cars_sold_3mnth_seg_mean", "cars_sold_6mnth_seg_mean", "cars_sold_1mnth_mmt_mean", "cars_sold_3mnth_mmt_mean", "cars_sold_6mnth_mmt_mean", "cars_sold_1mnth_mmt_per_segment_mean", "cars_sold_3mnth_mmt_per_segment_mean", "cars_sold_6mnth_mmt_per_segment_mean", "cars_sold_1mnth_mmt_per_fleet_mean", "cars_sold_3mnth_mmt_per_fleet_mean", "cars_sold_6mnth_mmt_per_fleet_mean", "cars_sold_1mnth_seg_per_fleet_mean", "cars_sold_3mnth_seg_per_fleet_mean", "cars_sold_6mnth_seg_per_fleet_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_mean", "me_pcp_2_2012q2_mean", "me_pcp_3_2012q2_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_only_crisis_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_1_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_2_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_3_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_4_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_5_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_6_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_7_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_8_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_9_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_10_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_11_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_12_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_13_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_14_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_only_crisis_1_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_only_crisis_2_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_only_crisis_3_mean")
```

I have tried to narrow down if there is a problem with one of the strings in the list but by spliting the list into shorter lists I have been able to include all of them at some point.

Since I have been able to create longer vectors (in terms of amount of variables) in the past I am at a loss as to what is wrong.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Split your vector initialization in multiple lines. I mean one vector over several lines.

Comment: don't think that it's a mispell  because r-studio would mark it in a different color and you'll see it immediatly

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit to the width of a line that R reads, splitting your command into multiple line solves the issue. I am not sure if we can change the settings to increase the length of line that R reads. Below command works:

```
myvars <- c("sale_year", "sale_mnth", "end_duration_mean", "ln_end_duration_mean", "one_by_end_duration_mean", "end_duration_class_2_dummy_mean", "end_duration_class_3_dummy_mean", "end_duration_class_4_dummy_mean", "end_duration_class_5_dummy_mean", "end_duration_class_6_dummy_mean", "end_duration_class_23_dummy_mean", "end_duration_class_56_dummy_mean", "on_dummy_mean", "of_dummy_mean", "n_dummy_mean", "nof_dummy_mean", "non_dummy_mean", "ofon_dummy_mean", "nn_dummy_mean", "nf_dummy_mean", "lifecycle_sale_mean", "mnth_vs_new_model_mean", "sin_mnth_vs_new_model_mean", "ln_mnth_vs_new_model_mean", "sqrt_mnth_vs_new_model_mean", "mnth_vs_new_model_n_mean", "mnth_vs_new_model_of_mean", "mnth_vs_new_model_on_mean", "mnth_vs_new_model_nof_mean", "mnth_vs_new_model_non_mean", "mnth_vs_new_model_ofon_mean", "sqrt_mnth_vs_new_model_n_mean", "sqrt_mnth_vs_new_model_of_mean", "sqrt_mnth_vs_new_model_on_mean", "sqrt_mnth_vs_new_model_nof_mean", "sqrt_mnth_vs_new_model_non_mean", "sqrt_mnth_vs_new_model_ofon_mean", "ln_mnth_vs_new_model_n_mean", "ln_mnth_vs_new_model_of_mean", "ln_mnth_vs_new_model_on_mean", "ln_mnth_vs_new_model_nof_mean", "ln_mnth_vs_new_model_non_mean", "ln_mnth_vs_new_model_ofon_mean", "sin_mnth_vs_new_model_n_mean", "sin_mnth_vs_new_model_of_mean", "sin_mnth_vs_new_model_on_mean", "sin_mnth_vs_new_model_nof_mean", "sin_mnth_vs_new_model_non_mean", "sin_mnth_vs_new_model_ofon_mean", "ln_lifecycle_sale_mean", "sqrt_lifecycle_sale_mean", "lifecycle_sale_n_mean", "lifecycle_sale_of_mean", "lifecycle_sale_on_mean", "lifecycle_sale_nof_mean", "lifecycle_sale_non_mean", "lifecycle_sale_ofon_mean", "sqrt_lifecycle_sale_n_mean", "sqrt_lifecycle_sale_of_mean", "sqrt_lifecycle_sale_on_mean", "sqrt_lifecycle_sale_nof_mean", "sqrt_lifecycle_sale_non_mean", "sqrt_lifecycle_sale_ofon_mean", "ln_lifecycle_sale_n_mean", "ln_lifecycle_sale_of_mean", "ln_lifecycle_sale_on_mean", "ln_lifecycle_sale_nof_mean", "ln_lifecycle_sale_non_mean", "ln_lifecycle_sale_ofon_mean", "lifecycle_age_mean", "ln_lifecycle_age_mean", "sin_lifecycle_age_mean", "sqrt_lifecycle_age_mean", "lifecycle_age_class_mean", "lifecycle_age_n_mean", "ln_lifecycle_age_n_mean", "sin_lifecycle_age_n_mean", "sqrt_lifecycle_age_n_mean", "lifecycle_age_of_mean", "ln_lifecycle_age_of_mean", "sin_lifecycle_age_of_mean", "sqrt_lifecycle_age_of_mean", "lifecycle_age_on_mean", "ln_lifecycle_age_on_mean", "sin_lifecycle_age_on_mean", "sqrt_lifecycle_age_on_mean", "lifecycle_age_nof_mean", "ln_lifecycle_age_nof_mean", "sin_lifecycle_age_nof_mean", "sqrt_lifecycle_age_nof_mean", "lifecycle_age_non_mean", "ln_lifecycle_age_non_mean", "sin_lifecycle_age_non_mean", "sqrt_lifecycle_age_non_mean", "lifecycle_age_ofon_mean", "ln_lifecycle_age_ofon_mean", "sin_lifecycle_age_ofon_mean", "sqrt_lifecycle_age_ofon_mean", "segment_small_dummy_mean", "segment_medium_dummy_mean", "segment_high_dummy_mean", "segment_monovolumes_dummy_mean", "segment_cabrio_dummy_mean", "segment_suv_dummy_mean", "other_segment_dummy_mean", "cat_prijs_mean", "ln_cat_prijs_mean", "one_by_cat_prijs_mean", "rw_per_mean", "optie_per_mean", "optie_per_2_mean", "optie_per_3_mean", "ln_optie_per_mean", "one_by_optie_per_mean", "accs_per_mean", "accs_per_2_mean", "accs_per_3_mean", "ln_accs_per_mean", "one_by_accs_per_mean", "optie_accs_per_mean", "optie_accs_per_2_mean", "optie_accs_per_3_mean", "ln_optie_accs_per_mean", "one_by_optie_accs_per_mean", "schade_per_mean", "schade_dummy_mean", "schade_per_2_mean", "schade_per_3_mean", "ln_schade_per_mean", "one_by_schade_per_mean", "kort_per_mean", "kort_per_2_mean", "kort_per_3_mean", "ln_kort_per_mean", "one_by_kort_per_mean", "end_kms_mean", "end_kms_2_mean", "end_kms_3_mean", "ln_end_kms_mean", "one_by_end_kms_mean", "end_kms_class_mean", "kms_per_year_mean", "lux_dummy_mean", "doors2_dummy_mean", "doors3_dummy_mean", "ln_motor_kw_mean", "sqrt_motor_kw_mean", "one_by_motor_kw_mean", "motor_pk_per_cc_mean", "euro3_dummy_mean", "euro4_dummy_mean", "euro5_dummy_mean", "euro6_dummy_mean", "tijd_mean", "wit_dummy_mean", "break_dummy_mean", "cabrio_dummy_mean", 
            "mono_dummy_mean", "viermaalvier_dummy_mean", "berline_dummy_mean", "sport_dummy_mean", "coupe_dummy_mean", "roadster_dummy_mean", "missing_bodytype_dummy_mean", "uitvoering_base_dummy_mean", "uitvoering_comfort_dummy_mean", "uitvoering_high_dummy_mean", "uitvoering_sport_dummy_mean", "uitvoering_vip_dummy_mean", "tractie_v_dummy_mean", "tractie_a_dummy_mean", "tractie_4x4_dummy_mean", "tractie_unk_dummy_mean", "business_dummy_mean", "sale_b2b_dummy_mean", "sale_b2c_dummy_mean", "ck_kms_10000_mean", "ck_kms_30000_mean", "ck_kms_50000_mean", "ck_kms_70000_mean", "ck_kms_90000_mean", "ck_kms_110000_mean", "ck_kms_130000_mean", "ck_kms_150000_mean", "ck_kms_170000_mean", "ck_kms_190000_mean", "ck_kms_210000_mean", "ck_dur_1_mean", "ck_dur_2_mean", "ck_dur_3_mean", "ck_dur_4_mean", "ck_dur_5_mean", "ck_dur_6_mean", "ck_kpy_5000_mean", "ck_kpy_15000_mean", "ck_kpy_22500_mean", "ck_kpy_27500_mean", "ck_kpy_32500_mean", "ck_kpy_37500_mean", "ck_kpy_42500_mean", "ck_kpy_47500_mean", "ck_kpy_55000_mean", "ck_kpy_65000_mean", "kms_k60000_dummy_mean", "kms_k70000_dummy_mean", "kms_k80000_dummy_mean", "kms_k90000_dummy_mean", "kms_k100000_dummy_mean", "kms_k110000_dummy_mean", "kms_k120000_dummy_mean", "kms_g130000_dummy_mean", "kms_g140000_dummy_mean", "kms_g150000_dummy_mean", "kms_g160000_dummy_mean", "kms_per_year_k10000_dummy_mean", "kms_per_year_k20000_dummy_mean", "kms_per_year_k30000_dummy_mean", "kms_per_year_g40000_dummy_mean", "kms_per_year_g50000_dummy_mean", "kms_per_year_g60000_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_l100_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_100_110_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_110_120_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_120_130_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_130_140_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_140_150_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_150_160_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_160_170_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_170_180_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_180_190_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_190_200_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_m200_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_l110_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_l120_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_l130_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_l140_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_l150_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_l160_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_l170_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_l180_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_l190_dummy_mean", "motor_pk_l200_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_l1000_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_1000_1250_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_1250_1500_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_1500_1750_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_1750_2000_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_2000_2250_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_2250_2500_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_2500_2750_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_2750_3000_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_m3000_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_l1250_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_l1500_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_l1750_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_l2000_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_l2250_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_l2500_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_l2750_dummy_mean", "motor_inhoud_l3000_dummy_mean", "kort_m5_dummy_mean", "kort_m10_dummy_mean", "kort_m15_dummy_mean", "kort_m20_dummy_mean", "kort_0to5_dummy_mean", "kort_5to10_dummy_mean", "kort_10to15_dummy_mean", "kort_15to20_dummy_mean", "optie_m5_dummy_mean", "optie_m10_dummy_mean", "optie_m15_dummy_mean", "optie_m20_dummy_mean", "optie_0to5_dummy_mean", "optie_5to10_dummy_mean", "optie_10to15_dummy_mean", "optie_15to20_dummy_mean", "optie_accs_m5_dummy_mean", "optie_accs_m10_dummy_mean", "optie_accs_m15_dummy_mean", "optie_accs_m20_dummy_mean", "optie_accs_0to5_dummy_mean", "optie_accs_5to10_dummy_mean", "optie_accs_10to15_dummy_mean", "optie_accs_15to20_dummy_mean", "schade_0to5_dummy_mean", "schade_5to10_dummy_mean", "schade_10to15_dummy_mean", "schade_15to20_dummy_mean", "schade_m5_dummy_mean", "schade_m10_dummy_mean", "schade_m15_dummy_mean", "schade_m20_dummy_mean", "kort_per_class_mean", "optie_per_class_mean", "schade_per_class_mean", "motor_pk_class_mean", "motor_inhoud_class_mean", "zwart_dummy_mean", "rood_dummy_mean", "bruin_dummy_mean", "geel_dummy_mean", "groen_dummy_mean", "blauw_dummy_mean", "grijs_dummy_mean", "geen_kleur_dummy_mean", "dubbel_kleur_dummy_mean", "automaat_2000min_dummy_mean", "automaat_2000plus_dummy_mean", "dal_dummy_mean", "premiumlease_dummy_mean", "saablease_dummy_mean", 
            "leasesense_dummy_mean", "privatesale_dummy_mean", "cars_sold_1mnth_mean", "cars_sold_3mnth_mean", "cars_sold_6mnth_mean", "cars_sold_1mnth_seg_mean", "cars_sold_3mnth_seg_mean", "cars_sold_6mnth_seg_mean", "cars_sold_1mnth_mmt_mean", "cars_sold_3mnth_mmt_mean", "cars_sold_6mnth_mmt_mean", "cars_sold_1mnth_mmt_per_segment_mean", "cars_sold_3mnth_mmt_per_segment_mean", "cars_sold_6mnth_mmt_per_segment_mean", "cars_sold_1mnth_mmt_per_fleet_mean", "cars_sold_3mnth_mmt_per_fleet_mean", "cars_sold_6mnth_mmt_per_fleet_mean", "cars_sold_1mnth_seg_per_fleet_mean", "cars_sold_3mnth_seg_per_fleet_mean", "cars_sold_6mnth_seg_per_fleet_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_mean", "me_pcp_2_2012q2_mean", "me_pcp_3_2012q2_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_only_crisis_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_1_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_2_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_3_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_4_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_5_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_6_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_7_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_8_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_9_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_10_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_11_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_12_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_13_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_14_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_only_crisis_1_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_only_crisis_2_mean", "me_pcp_1_2012q2_neg_only_crisis_3_mean")
```